# FancyBox Jquery resize

Tags: jquery, resize, fancybox

When I open fancybox I'm getting two different displays. This happens across all browsers I've tested - one is fine and sized correctly (the example on the left of my image below) and the second is stretched to 100%. I've cleared cache and checked on different machines - and I keep getting both results. Is there a way I can insure that fancybox is never wider than 700px.

[Picture of issue](http://snapsay.com/issue.jpg)

In the jquery.fancybox.js file I have the following:

```
defaults: {
  padding : 15,
  margin  : 20,
  width     : 800,
  height    : 600,
  minWidth  : 100,
  minHeight : 100,
  maxWidth  : 700,
  maxHeight : 800,
```

Please assist as this is driving me crazy :-)

Comment: got a link? it would be much easier